# Can an ArrayList be a two-dimensional array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm brand new to Java, programming, and StackOverflow. I need to use a list where I can add or remove things and don't know the initial size (like ArrayList) but I also need it to be two dimensional. I've read on Google and StackOverflow and I can't find a concrete answer. Is this a possibility? And if not can you point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ArrayList of ArrayLists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> arrList2D = new ArrayList<ArrayList>(2);

arrList2D.add(new ArrayList());
arrList2D.add(new ArrayList());
```

`arrList2D` is a 2D ArrayList.

Comment: Yay thanks!! I've been messing around with my code for a few hours so I figured I'd just ask. I'm glad I did! High Five yo!

Comment: Note that the `2` in the argument to the constructor has nothing to do with it being 2d. That is just the initial capacity (can grow later) of the first dimension.

Answer (score 3):

well you can always try writing a simple code and see if this work.
By the way you can use Array list in array list and I am pretty sure it will be a very bad idea.

Comment: what is so very bad about an `ArrayList<ArrayList<?>>` ?

Comment: @Thilo there is no guarantee that the member lists will be the same size, so you'll constantly have to be careful about indexing. It's not bad per se, but it gets tricky.

Comment: That is the same with a two dimensional array, and it has advantages, too.

Comment: @Thilo the reason jackrabbit described is the one I was thinking . secondly the way arraylist grows is by copying the existing arrays into the next memory location. Having the double dimension array list , I think, will lead to big overhead when the number of rows are growing.